# Terraform Depedency graph is too small to read

Tags: github, svg, terraform, graphviz

I have `GraphViz` for Ubuntu installed as directed by the official website. I am able to draw the Terraform dependency graph for the resources using the Terraform command `terraform graph | dot -Tsvg > graph.svg`. However, when I view the SVG file created using a VS code plugin it appears very small to be readable.

Viewing the image on the GitHub repo, it is still too small to be readable.

Where could I have gone wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there is a better way.

Comment: Normally `svg` can be zoomed in/out when viewed.

Comment: For doxygen we generate the svg graphs as well and do some post processing on the graphs to get them zoomable. See e.g. the collaboration diagram on the page https://doxygen.github.io/doxygen-docs/d9/d0e/class_doc_node.html and the manipulated svg file https://doxygen.github.io/doxygen-docs/d7/d7c/class_doc_node__coll__graph.svg and the original: https://doxygen.github.io/doxygen-docs/d7/d7c/class_doc_node__coll__graph_org.svg Maybe this gives you some ideas.

Comment: @albert that for Insight on Doxygen - looks to be an amazing tool, will surely check it out deeply for other use cases. cheers